# Black screen after screen unlock while application is running in android

Tags: android

I want to keep screen orientation and application when I lock the screen.

But when I unlock the screen after lock screen while application is running,
then device shows only black screen. It reacts by touch (checked by log) but shows nothing.
I'm using TextureView with fullscreen size.

I use Samsung Galaxy Note 4 for developing, and its android version is 4.4.4.

1. Launch application(which is developed by me).
2. Lock screen.
3. Unlock screen.
4. **Black screen shown.** <== My Problem

Log for launch application, screen lock, screen unlock about WindowManager is following.

```
11-14 18:55:26.132: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:26.132: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:26.132: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:26.132: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:26.132: V/WindowManager(3409): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=0, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
11-14 18:55:26.142: D/SamsungWindowManager(3409): setRotationLw() : rotation=1
11-14 18:55:26.187: D/WindowManager(3409): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called before config changed.
11-14 18:55:26.217: D/CenterBarWindow(21578): onConfigurationChanged point = Point(1280, 720)
11-14 18:55:26.217: D/WindowManager(3409): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called before config changed.
11-14 18:55:26.477: I/WindowManager(3409): Screen frozen for +337ms due to Window{452f1008 u0 Starting net.herit.iotwm.smartphone}
11-14 18:55:27.062: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:27.062: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:27.062: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:27.062: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:27.062: V/WindowManager(3409): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=0, last=1); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
11-14 18:55:30.532: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:30.532: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:30.532: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:30.532: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:30.532: V/WindowManager(3409): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=1, last=1); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
11-14 18:55:30.547: D/SamsungWindowManager(3409): setRotationLw() : rotation=0
11-14 18:55:30.567: D/WindowManager(3409): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called before config changed.
11-14 18:55:30.587: D/WindowManager(3409): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called before config changed.
11-14 18:55:30.597: D/CenterBarWindow(21578): onConfigurationChanged point = Point(720, 1280)
11-14 18:55:30.807: I/WindowManager(3409): Screen frozen for +257ms due to Window{43593a68 u0 Keyguard}
11-14 18:55:31.287: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:31.287: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:31.287: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:31.287: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:31.287: V/WindowManager(3409): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=1, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
11-14 18:55:32.472: E/SamsungWindowManager(3409): mCoreNumLockHelper.acquire
11-14 18:55:32.517: I/WindowManager(3409): Lock screen displayed!
11-14 18:55:34.717: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:34.717: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:34.717: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:34.717: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:34.717: V/WindowManager(3409): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=0, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
11-14 18:55:34.727: D/SamsungWindowManager(3409): setRotationLw() : rotation=1
11-14 18:55:34.747: D/WindowManager(3409): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called before config changed.
11-14 18:55:34.757: D/WindowManager(3409): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called before config changed.
11-14 18:55:34.797: D/CenterBarWindow(21578): onConfigurationChanged point = Point(1280, 720)
11-14 18:55:34.902: I/WindowManager(3409): Screen frozen for +169ms due to Window{446612a8 u0 MultiWindowTrayService/AppListWindow 0}
11-14 18:55:35.337: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:35.337: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:35.337: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
11-14 18:55:35.337: V/WindowOrientationListener(3409): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
11-14 18:55:35.337: V/WindowManager(3409): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=0, last=1); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
```

Manifest.xml is shown below.

```
...
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
...
```

I'm sorry for my bad English. I really want to solve this problem.
Somebody help me!

Comment: what do you want? use your always vertical? or u want use vertical and horizontal?

Comment: @AndresCardenasPardo Hello, I need to use always horizontal.

Comment: I answer your question below, here the link for more info [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html]

Comment: Are you handling orientation through some code? if yes, posting that would be useful.

Comment: @rDroid I handle orientation only using Manifest.xml file.

Comment: this happens only for your app?

Comment: @rDroid Yes. I got something wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: remove android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: I assume you're using onPause() and onResume()?? Correct?

Comment: @rDroid If I remove that line, the screen orientation is changeable. I don't want screen change dependent on device configuration.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk exactly!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk And I'm using textureview with fullscreen size.

Comment: and there exactly is what could be causing the issue. I suggest some code would help.
you doing something in onConfigChanged or something or in onPause or onResume?

Comment: @rDroid Im doing nothing on those methods. I think this problem is caused by textureview.

Answer (score 1):

Then the solution is easy:

put this in your manifest

```
<android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: I already done it. Orientation is not main issue. It shows black screen when I unlock the screen after screen locked manually while application is running.